# Date arithmetic in QueryDSL

Tags: querydsl

I would like to express the following (Oracle) query in QueryDSL:

```
SELECT * FROM entity WHERE entity.created < (sysdate - entity.delayInDays)
```

I.e. I want to do date arithmetic. Unfortunately, a `com.mysema.query.types.path.DateTimePath` (which is returned by `QEntity.entity.created`) does not contain any methods for addition/subtraction, only for comparison (like `before` or `gt`).

I found `com.mysema.query.types.Ops.DateTimeOps` but there is nothing there to help me, either.

Am I missing something or does QueryDSL just not support date arithmetic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. Currently Querydsl doesn't support date arithmetic, but feel free to create an issue for it https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I followed your advice and created an issue (https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/347). Btw: I really like QueryDSL and use it a lot!